# Attempt to use an extended __device__ lambda in a context that requires querying its return type in host code

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, thrust

I'm receiving the compiler error

```
static_assert failed: 'Attempt to use an extended __device__ lambda in a context that requires querying its return type in host code. Use a named function object, a __host__ __device__ lambda, or cuda::proclaim_return_type instead.'
```

when compiling this code:

```
thrust::device_vector<float2> a;
thrust::device_vector<float> b;

float param1, param2;
float2 param3;

thrust::transform_reduce(
    thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(a.begin(), b.begin())),
    thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(a.end(), b.end())),
    [param1, param2, param3] __device__ (thrust::tuple<float2, float> const& tuple)
    {
        /* do something and return a float2 */
    },
    float2{},
    [] __device__ (float2 const& first, float2 const& second)
    {
        float2 result{};
        result.x = first.x + second.x;
        result.y = first.y + second.y;
        return result;
    });
```

How can I rewrite this code so that it compiles? I'm new to CUDA/Thrust and its quite obscure to me how I need to deal with this problem.

(BTW, do I really need the complicaed "transformation" function here? `thrust::plus<float2>` doesn't work.)

Comment: FYI: [Thrust issue about problems with pure `__device__` lambdas on github](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/issues/779).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I rewrite this code so that it compiles?

A possible solution seems to be indicated in the assert message you posted in your question:

> static_assert failed: 'Attempt to use an extended `__device__` lambda in a context that requires querying its return type in host code. Use a named function object, **a `__host__ __device__` lambda**, or cuda::proclaim_return_type instead.'

When I change each lambda to be decorated with `__host__ __device__` instead of just `__device__` then [the code compiles for me on CUDA 12.1](https://godbolt.org/z/bc7qxvs1j)

> (BTW, do I really need the complicaed "transformation" function here? thrust::plus doesn't work.)

CUDA doesn't provide arithmetic operators for the vector types supplied by CUDA, and AFAIK [thrust](https://thrust.github.io/doc/structthrust_1_1plus.html) doesn't either:

> then x+y must be defined

So you'll need to provide your own definition to add `float2` types, i.e.

```cpp
__host__ __device__ __forceinline__
float2 operator+(float2 left, float2 right) noexcept {
    return float2{left.x + right.x,
                  left.y + right.y};
}
```

will allow you to use `thrust::plus<float2>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does decorating  with `__host__ __device__` instead of `__device__` have any performance impact or is the compiled code the same?

Comment: Ah, it doesn't work. I'm calling a `__device__` function inside the lambda and the compiler now gives an error stating that this is not allowed: *Calling a __device__ function from a __host__ __device__ function("operator()") is not allowed*

Comment: I guess using a named function object is the only solution ...

Comment: I can't really guess at code you haven't shown. I can pretty much only work with what you have shown.  Without knowing what your nested `__device__` function looks like, I guess I would try decorating it `__host__ __device__` also.  Decorating a function `__host__ __device__` shouldn't have any impact on the device code generation as compared to the case where it is decorated `__device__` only.

Comment: Sure, sorry, I did not thought about that this might be crucial as I wrote the question. Thank you for your help.